Captions not centered with the standalone class and varwidth option + caption package
(Edit: Question with screenshots so, I hope, clearer.)
The following document, whose class is standalone used with its varwidth option, shows that the floats' captions are centered, as with the usual classes.
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
% \documentclass[preview]{standalone}
% \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  A graphic
  \caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


However, as soon as the caption package is loaded, these captions are no longer centered.

How to have captions centered with the standalone class used with its varwidth option and the caption package loaded?
(FWIW, with the standalone class used with its preview (instead of varwidth) option and the caption package loaded, the captions are centered again.)

with caption you get a warning from varwidth that it can reprocess all content.

@UlrikeFischer I noticed that warning. Is it this inability to reprocess all content that prevents captions from being centered?

@UlrikeFischer Because, apart from this centering problem, everything seems to be going well.

no the caption is not centered because you are not centering it. Try with \captionsetup{justification=centering}. But the warning means that varwidth can set the width.

@UlrikeFischer Indeed, that does the trick: thanks! Would you like to turn your comment into an answer in order I can accept it?

The varwidth option should reduce the width to the minimum needed, but here is just goes with \textwidth (345pt), which makes it sort of useless.

@JohnKormylo In my real usecase, I use this option with varwidth=⟨width⟩.

Ah, you are doing the old "infinite page" trick!

Sorry, but centering has no meaning in standalone. The varwidth option is meant to use also vertical material in the document body, but varwidth will use the least possible width. In other words the total width is unspecified, so centering makes no sense.
Besides, varwidth boxes don't play well with caption.
In order to center something you have to specify a width with respect to which centering takes place.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\parbox{5cm}{
    \centering
    A graphic
    \captionof{figure}{A caption.}
}

\end{document}


Just to clarify the working of varwidth:
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}

aaaaaaa
bbbbb \\
ccccc

\end{document}


If I add \\ at the end of the first line


Sorry, I don't see your point. In the MWE I provided, if you load also the lipsum package and put \lipsum[1] just before the figure environment, you'll see “Figure 1: A caption.”: (a) centered without the caption package, (b) not centered with the caption package.

I hopefully clarified my OP with the lipsum addition and screenshots.

@DenisBitouzé No way \caption can work with varwidth

What do you mean by ‘can [not] work’? With \captionsetup{justification=centering} as Ulrike suggests, or with \captionsetup{justification=centerlast}, \captionseems to work withvarwidth`. OK, it's not exactly the same as with the usual classes, but it still gives an acceptable result.

I typically use the standalone class to import an image created in another file (e.g., with TikZ), and then I place it inside a figure environment, as LaTeX requires this to position the image properly.

In fact, that's the way I'm using the standalone class: I use it as a subterfuge to create “endless” page documents (the quotes are here since, unfortunately, the height of such pages is limited to around 5 meters, due to a TeX limitation). Hence my documents are supposed to include figure environments (and not the other way round).

Out of curiosity, may I ask why you want to have an endless page document?

I've explained the background in this question.

I can't see a valid reason for using a LaTeX float in a standalone document. I suggest you employ a center environment along with a \captionof directive to generate the caption.
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{caption} % for '\captionof' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  A graphic
  \captionof{figure}{A caption.}
\end{center}

\end{document}


As I said in my comment to Emanuele's answer, my use of the standalone class is a bit deviant ;) It's used to create ‘endless’ page documents. This use will be hidden from the document author in a class I'm working on, and I'd like to make for him the ‘usual’ environments, such as figure and table, as usual as possible.

The usual way to do an infinite page is to use a minipage (more robust than varwidth).  The standalone version of figure does not produce "not in outer par" errors.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  A graphic
  \caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}


Quite interesting, thanks!
